# Compare two text files and create another file which contain data along with matching prints

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two text files `eg1.txt` and `eg2.txt`.
I need to compare `eg1.txt` with respect to `eg2.txt` and create another file named `out.txt` .

`eg1.txt:`

```
000b423573 bdbaskbjejbajbkjfsjba
00036713dc sjgdjgdgdjadgygdeg263
00123fd351 heqgrg63u1quidg87gduq
0105517f52 vgfeeyguuiduiueyruuur
```

`eg2.txt`

```
0105517f52 vgfeeyguuiduiueyruuur
000b423573 bdbaskbjejbajbkjfsjba
7736001772 absjueui3ryhfuhuffh3u
00123fd351 heqgrg63u1quidg87gduq
```

output file `out.txt`

```
0105517f52 vgfeeyguuiduiueyruuur "Matching with eg1.txt"
000b423573 bdbaskbjejbajbkjfsjba "Matching with eg1.txt"
7736001772 absjueui3ryhfuhuffh3u "Not Matching with eg1.txt"
00123fd351 heqgrg63u1quidg87gduq "Matching with eg1.txt"
```

This is my current attempt:

```
file_1 = None
file_2 = None
with open("eg2.txt") as fin_1:
    file_1 = [line.strip() for line in fin_1.readlines()]
with open("eg1.txt") as fin_2:
    file_2 = [line.strip() for line in fin_2.readlines()]

file_3 = [] 
for line in file_2:
    if line not in file_1:
        file_3.append(line)

file_3 = '\n'.join(file_3)
with open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
    fout.write(file_3)
print(f"Wrote file:\n{file_3}")
```

Comment: You are trying to find if lines are in common to both line ?

Comment: yes if lines are present in both file then i need to print matching

Comment: comparison is done wrt eg1.txt.  i need to write all the lines in eg2.txt to out.txt and if lines are matching with eg1.txt then matching should be there with the lines else not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that in your example you name `eg2.txt` `file_1` and vice versa which leads you to find the lines in`eg1.txt` which do not exist in `eg2.txt`. Additionally, you have not yet added logic to concatenate the endings to the line, with can simply be done with `+`. With those slight modifications your code works.

Here is a runnable example!

```js
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open("eg1.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""000b423573 bdbaskbjejbajbkjfsjba
00036713dc sjgdjgdgdjadgygdeg263
00123fd351 heqgrg63u1quidg87gduq
0105517f52 vgfeeyguuiduiueyruuur""")

with open("eg2.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("""0105517f52 vgfeeyguuiduiueyruuur
000b423573 bdbaskbjejbajbkjfsjba
7736001772 absjueui3ryhfuhuffh3u
00123fd351 heqgrg63u1quidg87gduq""")


file_1 = None
file_2 = None
with open("eg1.txt") as fin_1:
    file_1 = [line.strip() for line in fin_1.readlines()]
with open("eg2.txt") as fin_2:
    file_2 = [line.strip() for line in fin_2.readlines()]

file_3 = []
for line in file_2:
    if line in file_1:
        file_3.append(line + '  "Matching with eg1.txt"')
    else:
        file_3.append(line + '  "Not Matching with eg1.txt"')

file_3 = '\n'.join(file_3)
with open("out.txt", "w") as fout:
    fout.write(file_3)
print(f"Wrote file:\n{file_3}")
```

```html
<script src="https://modularizer.github.io/pyprez/pyprez.min.js" theme="darcula"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to write lines along with strings when done comparing to out.txt

```
with open('eg1.txt') as fin_1, open('eg2.txt') as fin_2, open('out.txt', 'w') as fout:
    file_1, file_2 = fin_1.read().splitlines(), fin_2.read().splitlines()
    fout.write('\n'.join([f'{line} Matching with eg1.txt' if line in file_1
               else f'{line} Not Matching with eg1.txt' for line in file_2]))

# 0105517f52 vgfeeyguuiduiueyruuur Matching with eg1.txt
# 000b423573 bdbaskbjejbajbkjfsjba Matching with eg1.txt
# 7736001772 absjueui3ryhfuhuffh3u Not Matching with eg1.txt
# 00123fd351 heqgrg63u1quidg87gduq Matching with eg1.txt
```